# Importing modules in a file that declares decorators

Tags: python, decorator

This is my file structure:

```
annotations
    Helper.py
    annotations.py
test
    HelloWorld.py
```

This is `HelloWorld.py`, a simple `HelloWorld` class:

```
from annotations.annotations import annie

class HelloWorld:
    @annie.mydecorate
    def something():
        echo 'Hello World'
```

And within `annotations.py`, I'm just declaring some simple decorators:

```
from annotations.Helper import Helper

class annie:
    @staticmethod
    def mydecorate(func):
        Helper.prepare()
        print func.__name__
```

Here I get an error saying `No such module: Helper`. I guess this is happening when the module `HelloWorld` is being loaded, it is loading the annotations module, but the function is being called during the module being loaded at which time the `Helper` module is not loaded. I'm not sure how correct I am, but I am just looking for a solution here.

Is the problem something else? Can I import modules like I am doing in a file which declares decorators? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
rohan

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. Add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `annotations.py`, try:

```
import Helper
```

or (relative imports, Python 2.5 and up)

```
from . import Helper
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing wrong. I was assuming that the imports happen from the root of the file that imports it.. But boy would that be soo wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
annotations
    Helper.py
    annotations.py
    __init__.py
HelloWorld.py
```